# Zsh : for loop makes failing awk pattern

Tags: for-loop, zsh

I’m writing some scripts to manage users with specifics quotas on a server.

So, to apply a quota like 10GB to all the users in the group quota10, I’m using "setquota -p", but I have several groups.

So I made a script to manage all users from all groups.

```
#!/bin/zsh
groups=(1002 1007)
for gid in $groups
    echo $gid
    echo $(awk -F: '$4 == gid {print $1}' gid=$gid /etc/passwd)
```

But when I execute it, there is only the last group which give me users in this group.

#### /etc/passwd

```
kimino:x:1010:1002::/home/kimino:/bin/bash
kiminoo:x:1011:1007::/home/kiminoo:/bin/bash
```

#### /etc/group

```
quota10:x:1002:
quota20:x:1007:
```

#### Output of my script

```
# ./apply_quota_on_users.zsh
1002
1007
kiminoo
```

Do you have any idea about what’s wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your functions in a block:

```
for gid in $groups
do
    echo $gid
    echo $(awk -F: '$4 == gid {print $1}' gid=$gid /etc/passwd)
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I usually make for loop in one line, so I didn’t know this tip.